# Where can you go visa-free with an Australian Travel Document?

Tags: visa-free-entry, australian-residents

What are the Countries that allow Australia travel document holder? Want to take a trip in January,I have try bali but they don't

Comment: Is it an australian passport you're talking about? Or an Australian Convention Travel Document (CTD)?

Comment: If you mean a CTD, it seems the answer is ‘very few’, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Convention_Travel_Document

Answer (score 2):

### For Australian Convention Travel Document (refugees or non-Australian citizens)

According to [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Convention_Travel_Document) an Australia CTD holder is allowed into:

**Asia**

- Macau    - Visa on arrival   30 days maximum, visa issued upon arrival for MOP100

**Europe**

- Germany  - Visa not required 90 days (require CTD valid for at least 4 months)
- Hungary  - Visa not required 90 days
- Slovakia - Visa not required
- Slovenia - Visa not required

**Oceania**

- New Zealand  - Freedom of movement - For holders of Australian permanent visas only (according to Trans-Tasman Travel Arrangement)

### For Australian citizens and passport holders (2019)

According to [this website](https://amaryroad.com/australian-passport-visa-free-countries-citizens-holders/) an Australian passport holder has visa free conditions in:

**East Asia**

- Hong Kong - 90 days
- Japan - 90 days
- South Korea - 90 days
- Taiwan - 90 days

**Central Asia**

- Kazakhstan - 30 days
- Kyrgyzstan - 60 days

**Southeast Asia**

- Indonesia - 30 days
- Malaysia - 90 days
- Philippines - 30 days
- Singapore - 90 days
- Thailand - 30 days; maximum of 2 visit a year if not arriving by air
- Vietnam - 30 days if only staying in Phu Quoc

**Middle East / West Asia**

- Armenia - 180 days
- Cyprus - 90 days in every 180 days
- Georgia - 365 days
- Israel - 90 days
- Palestine
- Qatar - 30 days

**East Africa**

- Mauritius - 90 days
- Reunion - 90 days (French territory)
- Mayotte - 90 days (French territory)

**North Africa**

- Morocco - 90 days
- Tunisia - 90 days

**South Africa**

- Botswana - 90 days per year
- Gambia - 90 days
- Lesotho - 14 days
- Namibia - 90 days
- South Africa - 90 days
- Eswatini (Swaziland) - 30 days

**West Africa**

- Gambia - 90 days

**North America**

- Canada - 180 days
- Greenland - applies as Schengen visa; 90 days in 180 days
- Mexico - 180 days - get a tourist card
- United States of America - must get an ESTA; valid for two years

**Central America**

- Aruba - 90 days; can be extended up to 180 days
- Antigua and Barbuda - 30 days
- Bahamas - 90 days
- Barbados - 180 days
- Belize - 30 days
- Bermuda - 180 days; will be determined upon arrival
- Cayman Islands - 180 days
- Costa Rica - 90 days
- Curacao - 90 days
- Dominica - 180 days
- Dominican Republic - 90 days
- El Salvador - 90 days
- Guatemala - 90 days
- Grenada - 90 days
- Haiti - 90 days
- Honduras - 90 days
- Jamaica - 180 days
- Nicaragua - 90 days
- Saint Kitts and Nevis - 90 days
- Saint Lucia - 6 weeks
- Turks and Caicos - 90 days
- Panama - 180 days

**South America**

- Argentina - 90 days
- Brazil - 90 days starting June 17, 2019 - More tips on things to know before arriving - in Brazil
- Bolivia - 90 days
- Chile -90 days; must pay reciprocity fee of $117
- Colombia - 90 days; can be extended for another 90 days per calendar year - must show an exit ticket and Yellow Fever vaccination if coming from Brazil, Uganda, and Dominican Republic
- Ecuador - 90 days
- Guyana - 90 days
- Peru - 183 days - must show a return ticket
- Venezuela - 90 days
- Uruguay - 90 days

**Schengen Area States**

> Australian passport holders and citizens can enter, stay, and travel
>   in these countries for 90 days in a 180-day period. You can move
>   freely and cross the border without having to cross a border security
>   or passport checkpoint. Remember that it is 90 days for the entire
>   Schengen area not per country.

- Austria
- France
- Latvia
- Norway
- Spain
- Belgium
- Germany
- Liechtenstein
- Poland
- Switzerland
- Czech Republic
- Greece
- Lithuania
- Portugal
- Denmark
- Hungary
- Luxembourg
- Slovakia
- Estonia
- Iceland
- Malta
- Slovenia
- Finland
- Italy
- Netherlands
- Sweden

**Non-Schengen Countries**

- Albania - 90 days
- Andorra
- Belarus - 30 days must arrive visa Minsk Airport
- Bulgaria - 90 days within the 180-day period
- Croatia - 90 days within the 180-day period
- Ireland - 90 days, must show the purpose of travel, sufficient fund, return ticket, and accommodation booking
- Kosovo - 90 days
- Macedonia - 90 days
- Moldova - 90 days
- Monaco - 90 days within the 180-day
- Montenegro - 90 days
- Romania - 90 days within the 180-day
- San Marino
- Serbia - 90 days
- Ukraine - 90 days within 180-day
- United Kingdom - 180 days must show return ticket and accommodation booking
- Vatican City

**Oceania**

- Fiji - 120 days
- Kiribati - 120 days
- Micronesia - 30 days
- New Zealand - freedom of movement
- Palau - 180 days
- Vanuatu - 30 days

You can also check [this website](https://visalink.com.au/visa-quick-check) and [this newspaper article](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-6258647/The-countries-visit-just-using-Australian-passport-WITHOUT-having-visa.html) to verify visa requirements for Australian citizens...

Comment: Keep in mind that there as no direct flights to any of the CTD countries listed, so you would also need to find somewhere to transit that also allowed travel with one.